# Joomla adding menu to new templates?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I've gone through the admin settings - is there something I'm missing?
 I'm trying to add the main menu from the front page to a new template page.

Comment: Are you trying to assign the menu module to another page ? not only the homepage....

Comment: Need more info. Did you create a new menu item and the menu doesn't show up on that page? What template are you using? Is it custom or did you buy it from a template provider?

Comment: @Shaz yes, i'm just applying the main menu that is on the main page to a new custom template the joomla music collection template

Comment: Is this the music collection you are talking about? http://www.joomlamusicsolutions.com/en/music-collection.html

Comment: @Shaz yes that is the one i'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your scenario, you want to assign a menu (module) to another page(s) on your site.

This video will help you on this situation:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r83rUmCHSHM

Answer (score 0):

Your new template might be with different module position names from the old one. Every menu item creates a module so maybe you need to change the main menu module Position option to match the position of the new template. A quick view of the template positions can be done with adding `?tp=1` to the end of your site URL, like this - http://example.com/?tp=1 . Hope this helps you or someone else.

Answer (score -1):

. All you need to do is go to the 'module manager'---->select 'main menu'---->'position' (drop down menu in the right side).

Now open the drop down menu. Select the "main menu" position. **Make sure you select the main menu position of your current template**.(there are many 'main menu' positions under different templates.)

following link will be useful.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoNGSYI5XFM